# Create a nodejs module from a mongodb document to act as a model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, model, module

I want to create a model by encapsulation inside a node module a mongodb document with some functionality that has to do with that document. I was wondering what's the best pratice for doing this kind of thing?
also, is it a good idea to share the db instance with the global variable? if not how should I do it? (i'm using mongoskin)

The way i would like it to work:

```
1. get document from mongo -> pass to module constructor
2. get json via post request -> pass to the same module construсtor
```

i thought about something like this(using express):

Module(user.js):

```
var mongo = global.mongo;
var db = global.db;
db.bind('users');

function User(user, callback) {
  var self = this;

  self.name = user.name;
  self.email = user.email;

  if(user._id) {
    self._id = user._id;
  }
}

User.prototype.saveUser = function(callback) { ... }
User.getUserById = function(id, callback) { ... }

module.exports = User;
```

Route(users.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');

router.route('/').post(function(req, res) {
  new User(req.body, function(err, user) {
    if(err) { ... }
    user.saveUser(function(err, message) { ... }
  });
})

router.route('/:id').get(function(req, res) {
  User.getUserById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
    if(err) { ... }
    res.json(user);
  });
})
```

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for something like [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) which provides a higher level abstraction including schemas, models, and middleware?

Comment: I tried mongoose, i don't like bringing schemas into mongodb.

Comment: I tried again, seems after some research it is what i'm looking for. Thank :)